# Firebase error after adding Firebase to flutter project

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I added Firebase to my Flutter project by installing CLI. It was easy and quick but I am getting an error when I debug the app.

I am getting the error in main.dart at the initializeApp call.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();  <<< ERROR HERE
  runApp(const ProviderScope(
      child:
          DealDiligence())); 
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

**PlatformException (PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null))**

I originally started modifying the build.gradle files manually so I hope I didn't do something to mess them up.

How do I fix this?
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't follow the firebase configuration well.
If you used FlutterFire CLI as you said to add firebase to your flutter project it should create a file named `firebase_options.dart` contains the `DefaultFirebaseOptions` class, if you didn't find that file your configuration may not be right.
If you find it this is the solution for your problem:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
```

Hopefully this helped.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did have the file and adding the line of code you showed me worked.

Comment: You're welcome.